# doxygen with embedded graphviz uml diagrams

Tags: embed, doxygen, graphviz

I would like to embed own diagrams in my doxygen documentation. Is it possible to create your own diagrams using graphviz by textual description inside the sourcecode?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, have a look at the [\dot](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmddot) command.

Note that you can also include [message sequence charts](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/) via [\msc](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmddot). [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) files using [\diafile](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmddiafile) and as of release 1.8.8 also [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) diagrams via a [\startuml](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmdstartuml) ... [\enduml](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmdenduml) block.